# Cómo eliminar los datos en una tabla que ya existen en otra

Tags: sql, hive

Tengo este query pero al querer ejecutar me manda error

```
    delete from te_siais.tbafiliacion_prueba2 teafi
    where EXISTS
    (select null from lt_siais.tbafiliacion ltafi
    where teafi.cvepresup = ltafi.cvePresup
    and teafi.numsegsoc = ltafi.numsegsoc
    and teafi.agregado = ltafi.agregado
    )
```

> SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:42 missing EOF at 'teafi' near 'tbafiliacion_prueba2'

Comment: Parece que estás utilizando un alias `teafi` para la tabla. Intenta cambiar la primera línea por `delete teafi from te_siais.tbafiliacion_prueba2 teafi`. Nota, si no mal recuerdo, esta sintaxis no pertenece al estándar sql y puede que otros motores de base de datos, existentes o futuros no la reconozcan.

Comment: lo intenté pero tampoco me funcionó. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Cuando dices "tampoco me funcionó" te refieres a que no borró nada, o a que el mensaje de error de sintaxis es el mismo?

Comment: Probablemente el motor no soporte darle un alias a la tabla de la que se quiere borrar. Prueba dejarla sin alias, con lo que tendrás que usar el nombre completo de la tabla para calificar los nombres de las columnas en la sub-consulta del `where`.